# can you refrigerate risen bread dough

Tags: baking, bread, dough, rising

After I have let store bought frozen roll dough rise can I refrigerate to cook later! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

After you prove dough the yeast will continue to be active until they are killed by heat (or meet some other untimely demise). If you prove store-bought dough and then put it in the fridge, the cold temperature will slow down the metabolism of the yeast greatly, so yes, you are probably OK doing this for some period of time, but that's probably hours or overnight depending on how long you originally proved the dough.

If you prove too long your bread may become too sour or have an unpleasant crumb (it will probably collapse in the oven). If you are forming large bubbles in the bread you have probably proved too long. You can punch it down and prove again for the correct amount of time, or just bake straight away depending on the kind of bread. There are many recipes that call for proving in the fridge overnight to developer a deeper flavor.